# How to calculate depth of conditional nesting using netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, metrics, netbeans-plugins

I am doing some static code analysis on the files from the eclipse repository. One of the software metrics I want to use is depth of conditional nesting. But I can't find a way to do this on netbeans.